# How do I integrate DexGuard to my project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, dexguard

I have been looking for resources/documentation for integrating DexGuard to my project. I am using Android Studio.

I downloaded the libs and sample projects from DexGuard, but the have provided me no proper documentation on how I can integrate it with my project.

Following the given project is so confusing as I am quite new to this and I don't understand which files to copy and modify my Build.gradle.
Anyone who has experience using DexGuard for Android Studio please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

That might be because you haven´t ordered it from https://www.guardsquare.com/dexguard  but downloaded it elsewhere.

Normally you will have a **/docs** folder with an excellent documentation with an integration guide and an **/samples** folder with about 30 Sample Projects for any use case directly in the zip from their Website.

Comment: I´ve downloaded the latest version minutes ago and I have both. Which version do you have?